# mapping CSV file to POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

NAME,MOBILE,CITY,EMAIL

Alfreds,123566X,Delhi,abc@gmail.com

I have this file which has only two lines first is headers line second is values line.
Only two fileds are fixed in file NAME and MOBILE others are not fixed like file may be(NAME,MOBILE,PRODUCT) or may be (NAME,MOBILE,SUMMURY,ABC,XYZ) etc.

I want to map this file to entity class

```
public class MyPojo{
    private String NAME;
    private int MOBILE;
    private ???
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

Any help highly apperciated.
Suggest me any solution how can i do this.
Please help. Thanks in advance. New to programming world.

```
  File file=new File("file.csv");   
FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);   
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);  
String [] line1 = br.readLine().split(",");
String [] line2 = br.readLine().split(",");
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Hi Monika! You usually need to have written at least some code before asking a question about it on StackOverflow. Try finding a tutorial by searching for "read file java" then have a read through the String class's documentation if you want to do it from scratch. Or search for "java read csv". To store the unknown fields use a HashMap.

Comment: I can read the file and store in string after that I dont any idea of doing it how can i wrote the code. suggest me a way please @GKFX

Comment: Try this link, maybe it will help you. [Github](https://gist.github.com/asafary/9675488)

Comment: If you don't want to use any external dependency, you can this simple tutorial of baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/java-csv-file-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume, for the sake of a simple answer, that there are no commas in the actual data. If you want to parse a more general CSV file, it would be better to use a library if you lack the confidence to do it fully from scratch.

You need to split each string at the commas so use String.split (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). Reading the documentation tells you to pass a "regex" for the delimiter. You can read more about regexes [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) but to match just a comma you can use a literal comma.

```java
String header, data;
// Read file into the above strings
String[] headings = header.split(",");
String[] fields   = data.split(",");
```

Now you need to feed this into your class. Create a HashMap of the data and pass it to the constructor of Pojo:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
// Math.min selects the smaller of two values
int nItems = Math.min(headings.length, fields.length);
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(nItems);
// Start at the third item
for (int i = 2; i < nItems; i++) {
    map.put(headings[i], fields[i]);
}
Pojo pojo = new Pojo(fields[0], fields[1], map);
```

You then just need a constructor on Pojo that takes arguments `(String name, String mobile, Map<String,String> extraData)`.

```java
class Pojo {
    String name, mobile;
    Map<String,String> extraData;
    public Pojo(String name, String mobile, Map<String,String> extraData) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.extraData = new HashMap<String,String>(extraData);
    }
    // getters/setters....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it works. But can you please add a little more like if field position differs(email, name, city, mobile) how to run that for loop from i=2. Is there any way to do this also@GKFX

Comment: @Monikaverma You would need to start the loop at i=0 so that everything goes into the map, then retrieve and remove the name and mobile from the map with e.g. the `map.remove` method.